# Calling a member function pointer passed as template argument from lambda crashes

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
#include <functional>

struct Foo {
    void Callback()
    {}
};

template <class T, class P>
std::function<void()> MemCB(T &t, P p) 
{
    //return [&]() {t.Callback();}; //no issues if done this way.
    return [&]() {(t.*p)();};
}


int main()
{
    Foo f;
    std::function<void()> func = MemCB(f, &Foo::Callback);
    func();
}
```

This crashes (at least with optimizations turned on), and the issue is 
the attempt to call the member function here:

```
 return [&]() {(t.*p)();};
```

What's happening that causes issues here ?

Is there any way I can pass in an object `t` and a pointer to a member function `p` like I tried here and call `p` on the `t` object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You issue is that captured `p` become dangling "reference", change it to:

```
template <class T, class P>
std::function<void()> MemCB(T &t, P p) 
{
    return [&, p]() {(t.*p)();};
}
```

Comment: Your code is right. But I doubt that this is called "dangling reference." Should it not instead be "uncaptured local variable" or related?

Comment: @L.F. Nah, it *was* captured. Otherwise you wouldn't been able to use it at all. But it was captured by reference, rather than by value.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Oh yes. Sorry I was so stupid that I directly skipped the `&` symbol :)